# Upgrade SQL Server 2005 to 2008 or can we go to 2012

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

We are running SQL Server 2005 and we want to upgrade the instance.

Is it best to go to SQL 2008 or can we jump right to SQL 2012?

What is recommended and what should we look out for?

I am thinking about doing [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Newest version is often best choice, but that depends on applications, which use SQL server. (Of course hardware and OS should match too.)

If it is your in-house developed app, then you just have to run all tests against newest version, optionally fix problems and let it run.

If it is some 3rd party app, then you need to ask from app vendor, what SQL versions are (best) supported.

If you are developing and selling some application based on SQL server, then you have to support and maintain many versions of server (like we do - we support SQL2000 to SQL2008; SQL2012 is currently in testing phase).